# MongoDB atlas does not respect maxPoolSize

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

I have a Spring Boot application that connects Atlas. I have added *maxPoolSize* in connection string with value 200, but it always shows ~300 connections in Atlas dashboard. I know Atlas reserves few connections from pool, still the difference is very high.
It seems Atlas does not respect *maxPoolSize* parameter, or am I doing something wrong?
Note: In this project we are also using Quartz scheduler that takes connection from MongoClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have got my answer. We have 3 replica sets (P-S-S), and the `maxPoolSize` that I have assigned is 200. So, for each RS it assigns 200 connections that is already 600 and if Atlas assigns one connection to each RS for monitoring purpose then it becomes 603 connections.
And, above reason explains why my free tier of Atlas goes down (not accepting any request) after few days by reaching more than 500 connections (the max limit of connections allowed).

Credit: [Eric_Adam](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/poolsize-connection-count/113029/2)